# How to solve Access-Control-Allow-Origin in angular application using httpclient post request?

Tags: angular, odata

I am trying to call data URL using HttpClient post method, I have added headers along the post call. But I am still receiving the error as

> from origin 'http://localhost:6200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

But when I check in networks, I see the method shown as OPTIONS instead of post

```
Request Method: OPTIONS
```

Please find the HTTP call below

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.httpClient.post(this.url, options).pipe(map(this.extractData));
```

Can anyone help to solve this, I have added proxy.config.json file too below

```
"/sap/*": {
          "target": "http://t1525bms.somecompany.com:8080/sap",
          "secure": false
        }
```

In this way also i tried no use.

Comment: CORS headers are appended by the API, not the front-end. You'll want to allow CORS in your API routes to fix this.

Comment: Sorry not able to catch your point @ChristianScillitoe

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem installing in your browser an extension that allow CORS in yours response request.

There are different solutions you can find on chrome web store https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/cors?hl=en you only need to install the extension you prefer and the enable it, then your site should work fine.

**This is a "hack" that only allow you to develop and test your site but this method can't be used in production.**

As pointed out by Christian Scillitoe, CORS headers are appended in the response message provided from the server, so it is the server developer that have written the API that must allow your site to make the post request, the client isn't able to change this security behaviour in any way.

This is the only way to make your site work properly on prod environment.

Regarding the OPTIONS request instead a POST, the problem is due to the invalid headers you added to your request, if you need more info about you can find them searching about "preflight request" related to CORS error.